# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when run gulp server / gulp watch in my ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gulp, gulp-watch

On my ruby project when I try to run gulp (gulp server, gulp watch) I have the following error :

```
Users/workspace/website2019/gulpfile.babel.js:1
import del from 'del';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I don't get how can I fix it, if someone could help me please,

Answer (score 5):

you use babel transpilation with gulp because of the file `gulpfile.babel.js` For this reason you need to install babel. according to the [documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/javascript-and-gulpfiles) you need `@babel/register` and `@babel/preset-env` for transpiling your `import` syntax.

So run the following command in your project folder

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/register
```

Afterwards create the babel configuration file `.babelrc` in the root folder and add the following lines to it

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

make sure you have this line in package.json

```
"type": "module"
```